# Who first proved that a vanishing Riemann tensor is sufficient for the existence of Euclidean coordinates?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, ho.history-overview, curvature

Riemann famously introduced the notion of what we now call a Riemannian manifold and introduced the Riemann curvature tensor $R_{ijk}{}^l$, showing that it is an obstruction the local existence of Euclidean coordinates. It is now well known that $R_{ijk}{}^l = 0$ is also a **sufficient** condition for the local existence of Euclidean coordinates. So, who first proved this sufficiency?

It's quite possible that the original paper with the proof might be in German, or some other non-English language. In that case, what would be an English language reference translating/summarizing the contents of the corresponding original article?

**Edit:** For the purpose of collecting links to translations. Riemann's famous *Commentatio* paper, where he introduced the curvature tensor, is included in full English translation in the Appendix to

*Farwell, Ruth; Knee, Christopher*, [**The missing link: Riemann's ``Commentatio'', differential geometry and tensor analysis**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0315-0860(90)90002-U), Hist. Math. 17, No.3, 223-255 (1990). [ZBL0743.01017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0743.01017).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumably it was Riemann himself who proved the sufficiency of $R=0$ for the flatness. Spivak's Chapter 4 in Volume II of "A comprehensive introduction to differential geometry" is a good source on Riemann's work. It gives a translation of Riemann's inaugural lecture and of a part of his prize essay. At the end of the prize essay Riemann says (I am citing from Spivak):

> Given an acquaintance with the traditional methods, it is demonstrated without difficulty that these ... conditions when they are satisfied, suffice...

meaning the vanishing of the components of the curvature tensor. Later in Chapter 4, Spivak gives a proof of this claim by a method that could have been considered "traditional" by Riemann.

EDIT: It is possible that the first published proof is contained in

*Christoffel, E. B.*, [**On transformations of homogeneous differential forms of degree two.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1869.70.46), Borchardt J. LXX, 46-70 (1869). [ZBL02.0128.03](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:02.0128.03). [English translation included as Section 8 of Fagginger Auer, B. O. [*Christoffel revisited*.](http://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/203668) MSc thesis (2011, Utrecht)]

Christoffel deals with equivalence of two metrics, not just flatness.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Spivak's book. He does a fine job of guessing what the "traditional methods" of Riemann could have been. I see now that Riemann did make the *claim* of sufficiency. Still, I would like to know where an explicit proof was first published, even if in a monograph or a textbook.

Comment: I've edited my answer: Christoffel's article (in German) might be the source.

Comment: It seems rather difficult to extract a precise sufficiency result also from Christoffel's article. His equation (9), with one set of "Christoffel symbols" set to zero, gives a linear overdetermined PDE for the desired transformation to flat coordinates, whose integrability conditions include the vanishing of the Riemann tensor. But it is far from clear to me that the **existence** of solutions to such a system would have been obvious at the time. It seems that the [theorem of Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)) would only be published in 1877.

Comment: The above Riemann quote is [footnoted in a 2016 edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=l5oFDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA92) with the remark that “these computations were first provided” in consecutive 1869 papers of [Christoffel](http://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?02.0128.03) (already quoted) and [Lipschitz](http://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?02.0129.02). (And according to his biographer, Frobenius [extracted mathematical ideas](https://books.google.com/books?id=UzTBBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA169)  from both, as well as from [Jacobi and Clebsch](https://books.google.com/books?id=UzTBBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA188).)

Comment: A similar (more detailed) footnote is already in Riemann's [Collected Works (1892)](https://books.google.com/books?id=EzIPAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA405).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: Riemann wouldn't have needed Frobenius' Theorem to prove sufficiency. I have no idea whether this is how he would have done it, but, since he describes geodesic normal coordinates in his lecture when he defines his 'curvature measures', he might have noted that, by elementary ODE methods (existence and uniquenss for the initial value problem), one can show that the $g_{ij}$ are constant in geodesic normal coordinates when his curvature measures vanish everywhere. That would certainly have been well within 'traditional methods' since the Euler-Lagrange equations were well-known.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: Actually, Riemann itself do claim that the vanishing is sufficient. To be precise he claimed something sharper (as consequence of the counting argument: a metric depends on $n(n+1)/2$ functions a change of coordinates depends on $n$ hence should be $n(n-1)/2$  "excesses" or "invariants" .  In Spivak's volume II you can see the precise statement: it is enough that the sectional curvature vanish in $n(n-1)/2$ 2-planes to get flatness).  For more see : Antonio J. Di Scala, On an assertion in Riemann's Habilitationsvortrag, Enseign. Math. (2) 47 (2001), no. 1-2, 57–63

Comment: @RobertBryant, thanks that's another good point. But also, following up on Francois Ziegler's comments, the existence part of what we now call Frobenius' Theorem had already appeared in an equivalent form in a paper by [Deahna (1840)](https://eudml.org/doc/147105). This history is reviews with more context in [Hawkins (2005)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00407-004-0095-4). So it seems that there was no shortage of 'traditional methods' at the time. It is a bit disappointing to see how few people bothered to write out complete proofs in that era.